# Oreo ViewPager to display images from external storage filepaths

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-imageview, android-pageradapter

So I am very new to both Java and Android and am working on an app for a project.  Within the app I would like to have my own image gallery / viewer specifically for the images we will be saving with the app.  As such I want to use a ViewPager to slide through the images, and have created a custom pager adapter.  Here are the relevant files:

## CustomSwipeAdapter.java

```
package app.rpass;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();// list of file paths
    File[] listFile;
    private Context ctx;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(); //list of bitmaps

    public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == (LinearLayout)object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout,container,false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_count);
        String[] output = f.get(position).split("/");
        textView.setText(output[output.length-1]);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(images.get(position));
        container.addView(item_view);
        return item_view;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }

    public void getFromSdcard()
    {
        File file= new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"pictures");
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            try{
                listFile = file.listFiles();
                for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                    f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.i("File Error","No File Could be Created");
            }
        }
        else{
            Log.i("File Error","Filepath was not a directory");
        }

    }
    public void makeBitmaps(ArrayList<String> files){
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i ++){
            File imgFile = new File(files.get(i));
            if (imgFile.exists() && imgFile.canRead()){
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,50,50);
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(),options));
            }
        }
    }
    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }


}
```

## SlideActivity.java

```
package app.rpass;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class SlideActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomSwipeAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.swipe);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE =1;

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SlideActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i("Permissions Error","No permission inside of SlideActivity");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SlideActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        }

        adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this);
        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
            ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(SlideActivity.this);
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                dialog.setMessage("Loading Data...");
                dialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                adapter.getFromSdcard();
                adapter.makeBitmaps(adapter.f);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                if (dialog.isShowing()){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }.execute();
        //adapter.getFromSdcard();
        //adapter.makeBitmaps(adapter.f);
        //viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        //viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

## Swipe.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">



    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</RelativeLayout>
```

## swipe_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/image_count"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My issue is that the textViews are being created just fine, and are giving the appropriate filepaths, but the images are not appearing.  I've searched many other examples and still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I'm sure that I've been working on it so much that I simply have overlooked something.  Any input would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: one of your problems is that you are loading all images before using them in ViewPager. Just thing if you will have 1000 images 2000x3000 each. Do you think you have enough memory to load them all simultanuously? (actually it's even 10 such images likely enough to run your app out of memory)

Comment: Please do disk I/O on background threads. Part of that includes loading the images. For example, you might use one of the popular image-loading libraries (e.g., Glide, Picasso), rather than loading the images yourself. Those libraries load the images on background threads, help manage your memory, and can load the images on demand (rather than up front, as you are doing).

Comment: @CommonsWare  thank you for your reply.  I looked into Picasso and Glide and was not sure how to implement them from the CustomSwipeAdapter.  Would I use them within instantiateItem instead of setImageBitmap, or from another location?  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: "Would I use them within instantiateItem instead of setImageBitmap" -- yes.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thank you for the reply.  Are they all being loaded beforehand since they are being generated from the instatiateItem, or because of another method such as getFromSdcard or makeBitmaps?  Thank you!

Comment: `makeBitmaps` method loads them

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko would you be able to provide a code snipped of how you would go about changing what I have?  I changed `imageView.setImageBitmap(images.get(position));` into `Picasso.get().load(listFile[position]).into(imageView);` and still no image shows up.  I tried that change along with commenting out the `makeBitmaps` function and where it's called, and now the textView doesn't show up either, so it's safe to say that I am lost.  Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `swipe_layout.xml` the root `LinearLayout` has default orientation of `horizontal` and its first child `TextView` `layout_width` is set to `match_parent`. Hence, the second child `ImageView` is not visible. If you set the root view's orientation to vertical you should be able to see the `ImageView` too!

Edit: Uploaded screenshot
Android studio gives nice warning messages in these scenarios
[image]

Comment: Thank you!  That seems to have been the issue.  It worked as soon as I changed that.  I never would've figured that out on my own.  You saved me a lot of frustration.

Comment: I looked at the code and couldn't find anything off so was curious and ran the code in android studio to see what could be the issue. While looking at swipe_layout.xml, android studio showed a warning about linear layout orientation. I will update the answer with the screenshot

Comment: Yes, this is a good learning point for me to pay more attention, and it would've saved me a lot of time.  Thanks again for the time and help!